# Backbone model is undefined?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I can't understand why this.model would be defined in view.intialize() when I run this.model.fetch() on it but not in view.render().

[image: Chrome Developer Tools Screenshot]

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/example.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, exampleTemplate){

  var exampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function() {
      this.model.set({ _id: this.options.user_id });
      this.model.fetch({
        success: this.render,
        error: function(model, response) {
          console.log('ERROR FETCHING MODEL');
          console.log(model);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    },
    render: function() {
      console.log('HELLO FROM RENDER');
      console.log(this.model);
      console.log('GOODBYE FROM RENDER');
    }
  });

  return exampleView;

});
```

Comment: Is `this` getting de-referenced when success is being called? Maybe you need to bind it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because the `this` is being bound differently because render is being used as a callback, put the following line as the first line in your `initialize` method to bind `this` to the current view for the render method:

```
_.bindAll(this,"render");
```

[Underscore.js bindAll function](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll)

> Binds a number of methods on the object, specified by methodNames, to
>   be run in the context of that object whenever they are invoked. Very
>   handy for binding functions that are going to be used as event
>   handlers, which would otherwise be invoked with a fairly useless this.